# How to maintain access to an object of prototyped objects

Tags: javascript

I don't know if the question title makes sense, but one thing that I never learned was how to maintain control over objects created with the prototyping method. More specifically, objects that are not created via

```
var Joe = new Person('Joe');
Joe.sayName();
Joe.die();
```

But rather

```
var people = {};
var everyone = getAllPeopleFromSomewhere()

$.each(everyone, function(i,e){
     people[i] = new Person(e.name);
});

function die(id){
     people[id].die();  // obvious error
}

die(1);
```

I feel like I need another abstract system to manage an unknown amount of objects created in this way. But using an Id to reference them from an Object (or array) doesn't seem to be the way to go.

http://jsfiddle.net/vcsjx0s1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your code, the problem that you're experiencing stems from this line, in two places:

```
people[i] = new Person(e.name).sayName();
```

This can be fixed in two ways: splitting up the call, or returning `this` in the sayName function.

```
Person.prototype = {
    sayName: function () {
        $('#' + this.name).html(this.name);
        return this;
    },
    die : function(){
        $('#' + this.name).remove();
    }
};
```